# Refactoring component in smart/dumb component with a method using 2 arguments inside the smart component

Tags: angular, refactoring

I am trying to refactor my code following the smart/dumb component pattern in my angular project but I am stuck to the following case:

I have a component `CategoriesComponent` which contain a table I'd like to move to a dumb component `CategoriesTableComponent`.

So, I moved my tab template to my dumb component and linked my smart component to my dumb component with the Input and Output like this :

**categories.component.ts (smart component)**

```
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() theme: Theme;

  categories$: Observable<Category[]>;

  [...]

  /**
   * Delete a selected category on the server and the data store
   * @param category the category to delete
   */
  onDeleteCategory(themeId: string, category: Category) {
    this.categoryStoreService.deleteCategory(themeId, category);
  }
}
```

**categories.component.html (smart component)**

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="theme">

  [...]

  <app-categories-table [theme]="theme"
                        [categories]="categories$ | async"
                        (deleteCategory)="onDeleteCategory($event)"></app-categories-table>
</div>
```

**categories-table.component.ts (dumb component)**

```
export class CategoriesTableComponent {

  @Input() theme: Theme;
  @Input() categories: Category[];
  @Output() deleteCategory: EventEmitter<{themeId: string, category: Category}> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

}
```

**categories-table.component.html (dumb component)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let category of categories">
          [...]
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" title="delete category" (click)="deleteCategory.emit({theme._id, category})">
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
          [...]
```

But I have this error message in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Missing expected
>   : at column 27 in [deleteCategory.emit({theme._id, category})] in
>   ng:///AppModule/CategoriesTableComponent.html@26:87 ("        
>               ERROR
>   ->="deleteCategory.emit({theme._id, category})">
>                 
>       "): ng:///AppModule/CategoriesTableComponent.html@26:87

I know it's in the `deleteCategory.emit({theme._id, category})` declaration but I wondering if there is a way to do it inline without writing another method in the categories-table.component.ts

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you tried to provide a attribute name in the object that you emit?, category maybe, but theme._id is not a valid attribute name. Try deleteCategory.emit({themeId: theme._id, category})

Comment: As @daniel already pointed out, you have to add the explicit property names of the annon. object inline, otherwise there is no way to now which value belongs to which property.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It worked with `deleteCategory.emit({themeId: theme._id, category: category})`. I tried with `deleteCategory.emit({themeId: theme._id, category})`but I got the same error so I specified all the annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that you're missing a colon in

```
deleteCategory.emit({theme._id, category})
```

And indeed, this is not valid JavaScript. The correct code would be

```
deleteCategory.emit({themeId: theme._id, category: category})
```